# What is causing damage to my okra plant?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, leaves, damage, okra

What is causing the new leaves of our [Ladies' Fingers okra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okra) plants to become thin and curl? One of the plants has started to dry at the bottom part of the stem.

Location: Kolkata, India.

[image: Leaves curling]

[image: Stem drying]

Comment: Could you share how do you water your plants? How many plants are there in a container and what is the weather and temperature?

Comment: We water it bu mugs. This container has 2 plants. We have not more than 2 per container. The weather is hot and humid in summers. Temperatures ranges from 28 to 36 degree C and humidity is max at 80.

Comment: How often do you water? Another latest update on the plant condition?

Answer (score 1):

Leaf curl on vegetables can be a mosaic virus but is far more likely to be stress in non-commercial crops.

Too much fertilizer, too little humidity ( though 80% should be more than ample ) are the most likely causes.